# maven build process improvement

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a big project consists of 18 modules, and one parent project. this project takes about 1 hour to be built, and to improve this we have decided to use maven profiles to reduce the time by setting 4 different maven profiles, every one has set of the project modules.
the parent pom.xml modules was:

```
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
    <module>module4</module>
    <module>module5</module>
    <module>module6</module>
    <module>module7</module>
    <module>module8</module>
</modules>
```

now it is something like

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>main</id>
        <modules>
            <module>module1</module>
            <module>module2</module>
            <module>module3</module>
       </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile1</id>
        <modules>
            <module>module4</module>
            <module>module5</module>
       </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile2</id>
        <modules>
            <module>module6</module>
       </modules>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>profile3</id>
        <modules>
            <module>module7</module>
            <module>module8</module>
       </modules>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

we are using jenkins to build the project, and we provide the profile name in the maven options. the problem here is we see that the build takes almost the same time, and it shows in the log that sonar and clover coverage run on the whole project not that set of modules! any idea how to fix this? anyone has a better approach maybe?

Comment: Do you expect, for instance, module 6 to be analyzed when you run `profile2`? and modules 7 and 8 to be analyzed when you run `profile3`?

Comment: Yes! I have tried to use <includes> inside the profile definition, and it worked for some modules but for others didn't work not sure why. also the pom doesn't look good because I had to do that in each profile.

Comment: First really for only 18 modules it takes 1 hour to build? Why are running sonar with each build? clover coverage ? First remove the sonar analysis cause a sonar analysis makes only sense once a day..Run without any tests (are those tests really unit tests ?) Have you checked how long the tests take? Can be easily extracted from the log output in jenkins...(BTW: The profiles are not really the solution)..

Comment: Yes it does! sonar analysis and uploading the generated wars/jars takes that long. and yes it is just a unit test cases. what approach would you recommend other than using profiles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it is possible to [exclude a module from analysis](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMaven-ExcludingamodulefromSonarQubeanalysis), you're not going to get the results you desire from your current approach. That's because you expect to perform SonarQube analysis with each subset of the project. Likely, you expect each subset to show up as a different, browsable project in SonarQube. But that's not what will happen. Because each analysis will take place with the same project id, each profile will overlay the analyses of the previous ones.

Since your project seems to consist of 4 independent subsets, I'd suggest instead that you actually break the project into 4 separate ones, each with its own project id, tests, and analyses.

Comment: The analysis happens twice as I see, once on the profile modules, and the second time on the whole project. I think I will just disable it if I select a profile for faster dev testing and we will consider breaking it up in the future.

Comment: One thing I have noticed, some maven plugins have a concurrency issue and that will block the build process if there is any other build is going on so it is also something we had to fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [parallel builds](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Parallel+builds+in+Maven+3) in maven.